# Site Error: Unknown parameter in Content-Disposition

Tags: vb.net

I am facing an error while reading emails from server by using OpenPop.NET. Below is the Stack Trace of error:-

```
An unhandled exception has been occurred. The exception description is as follows :

System.ArgumentException: Unknown parameter in Content-Disposition. Ask developer to fix! Parameter: CHARSET
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderFieldParser.ParseContentDisposition(String headerValue)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeader(String headerName, String headerValue)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.MessageHeader.ParseHeaders(NameValueCollection headers)
at OpenPop.Mime.Header.HeaderExtractor.ExtractHeadersAndBody(Byte[] fullRawMessage, MessageHeader& headers, Byte[]& body)
at OpenPop.Mime.MessagePart.ParseMultiPartBody(Byte[] rawBody)
at OpenPop.Mime.Message..ctor(Byte[] rawMessageContent, Boolean parseBody)
at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage(Int32 messageNumber)
at BouncedEmailManager.MainWindow.Init()
```

Please check if anyone can help with this.

Thanks

Below is the Code:-

```
    InsertCustomEncodings()
    pop3Client = New Pop3Client()
    pop3Client.Connect(POPServer, POPPort, False)
    pop3Client.Authenticate(POPUser, POPPassword, AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword)
    Dim unreadMessageCount As Integer = pop3Client.GetMessageCount()
    For iMessage As Integer = 1 To unreadMessageCount
      Dim oPopMessage As OpenPOP.Mime.Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(iMessage)
      If Not oPopMessage Is Nothing Then
        Dim msg As Message = SaveMessage(con, oPopMessage, pop3Client, iMessage)
        If Not msg Is Nothing Then
          pop3Client.DeleteMessage(iMessage)
        End If
      End If
    Next
    pop3Client.Disconnect()


    Public Sub InsertCustomEncodings()
      OpenPop.Mime.Decode.EncodingFinder.AddMapping("iso-9999-9", Encoding.UTF8)
      OpenPop.Mime.Decode.EncodingFinder.AddMapping("ansi_x3.110-1983", Encoding.ASCII)
      OpenPop.Mime.Decode.EncodingFinder.FallbackDecoder = AddressOf CustomFallbackDecoder
    End Sub

    Private Function CustomFallbackDecoder(ByVal characterSet As String) As Encoding
      If characterSet.StartsWith("ansi") Then Return Encoding.ASCII
      Return Encoding.UTF8
    End Function
```

I am getting error on below line:-

Dim oPopMessage As OpenPOP.Mime.Message = pop3Client.GetMessage(iMessage)

Comment: Could we see any of the related code and possibly a same of the content. It appears you may be sending invalid charsets or forgetting to set a charset for the content of the header

Comment: Yes, Now I have added code above. Please check.